# Configure diagnostic settings for Table Services to Log Analytics workspace when storage account is of kind 'BlobStorage'

Tags: azure-storage-account, azure-policy

I am utilizing the policy 'Configure diagnostic settings for Table Services to Log Analytics workspace,' as outlined in the following link: https://www.azadvertizer.net/azpolicyadvertizer/2fb86bf3-d221-43d1-96d1-2434af34eaa0.html.

However, if the storage account housing the table service is of kind 'BlobStorage,' the policy cannot achieve compliance. This is due to the inability to locate the resource, resulting in the following error:

```
{"code":"OperationNotAllowedOnKind","message":"The operation is not allowed on account kind BlobStorage"}
```

As a solution, I aim to exclude all table services within storage accounts of type 'BlobStorage.' Unfortunately, I am encountering difficulties in implementing this exclusion correctly.

I considered the necessity of developing a custom policy and then excluding it in the policy rule. However, I am uncertain about the correct implementation. It might involve a structure similar to the following, but I suspect it may not function as intended:

```html
 ....
 "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableservices"
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "parent", // field does not exist, but it is an example
                "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
              },
               {
                "field": "kind",
                "notEquals": "BlobStorage"
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
....
```

it is even possible?

Comment: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/kind' is not supported in the Azure Policy rule.

Comment: @Nadia Hansen do you have a storage account kind `BlobStorage` with Table Services? Seems weird as `BlobStorage` is a legacy type and does not support tables. It is unstructured vs structured.

Comment: Even if that is the case, then you can use the `existenceCondition`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#deployifnotexists-evaluation - remember `policyRule` proceed the if-then if condition is true, whereas `existenceCondition` proceed if condition is false. So make the `type` in the `policyRule` equals `storageAccounts` and `kind` notEquals `BlobStorage`. Then make a check for `tableservices` in the `existenceCondition`, e.g. on the `name` != `default`. Untested, but should work. But I doubt your scenario is real with BlobStorage having TableServices